# Firestore SDK cannot mock DocumentSnapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, mocha.js

So I am trying to create a unit test for a firestore trigger, triggered by an `onCreate` event. The firebase documentation said to do this as so: [Firebase Unit Testing Background Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#constructing_test_data)

I copy the documentation pretty closely:

```
const snapshot = test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(
    {owner: 'testUserA', text: 'response from test user a'}, 
    'users/testUserA/questions/testQuestion/responses/testResponse'
);
```

This line gives the error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

At first I thought it might have to do with the `refPath` because it starts with u, but after changing it, the error is identical, so I assume it has to do with the first parameter, which seems like correct json, but apparently not. I'm kind of stumped.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You could post an issue to the project GitHub. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `test.cleanup()` in any other testing cases before you use `test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot()`? If any, remove them and run the test again